# make the input for a macro a button instead of a keyboard entry

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in excel that is currently running on control + s as the input that tells excel to run the macro. Is there a way to change it so that it isn't a keyboard entry but instead a button on the excel sheet?

Comment: Create a button, right click on button, assign macro to button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure it can be done. Insert any picture, shape or a button. Right click it and you will see "assign macro..." option. Choose one, confirm and next time you click on the object your macro will run.

If you want specifically a button, you can access it through quick access button as the top of excel (where you can see save and undo by default). Click little downwards arrow and select other commands...  There look for "button", but be careful not to have only "favorite commands" filtered.
(I have excel in czech so some names might be slightly different)